# internet explorer, ajax and cookie expiration

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, cookies

I've created a login form that uses ajax to send information to a php page where a cookie is set to expire  after 15 days. Everything works great in all browsers, except IE( tested with IE9). The cookie is created in IE but only works until I close the browser. AFter that, if I open the IE browser again the cookie is deleted.

The PHP:

```
$time = time() + 3600 * 24 * 15; setcookie("op_logged", $info, $time);
```

Is there something I need to do ?

Thnks

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Could you show your PHP code that is setting the cookie?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov $time = time() + 3600 * 24 * 15; setcookie("op_logged", $info, $time);

Comment: Make sure in `IE`'s `Internet Options->advanced` tab there is `Empty temporary internet Files Folder when browser is closed` is not checked.